# Access Google Cloud Memorystore from other project / network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-memorystore, vpc-peering

I have 2 Google Cloud Projects, `project-a` and `project-b`. In `project-a` I have a GKE cluster in the `default` network and in `project-b` I have a GCP Memorystore (Redis), in its own VPC network called `production-network`. The Redis instances is configured with Private service access and its authorized network is the `production-network`.

Now I need to (temporarily, for a couple of weeks) access this Redis instance from my old `project-a`. I can not move the Redis to a different network, nor can I move the GKE cluster to a different network. Therefore, I don't think I can use a shared VPC (if I understand correctly).

I want to avoid using a Redis proxy ([nutcracker/twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy)) and rather do it with GCP native tooling, if possible.

What is the correct way of going about this? Is VPC peering now possible? As far as I understand, the Memorystore instances run in their own VPC and VPC peering is not transitive.